# How to Upload Jquery.canvascrop Crop Image into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var rot = 0,ratio = 1;
        var CanvasCrop = $.CanvasCrop({
            cropBox : ".imageBox",
            imgSrc : "images/avatar.jpg",
            limitOver : 2
        });
        
        
        $('#upload-file').on('change', function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                CanvasCrop = $.CanvasCrop({
                    cropBox : ".imageBox",
                    imgSrc : e.target.result,
                    limitOver : 2
                });
                rot =0 ;
                ratio = 1;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            this.files = [];
        });
        
        $("#rotateLeft").on("click",function(){
            rot -= 90;
            rot = rot<0?270:rot;
            CanvasCrop.rotate(rot);
        });
        $("#rotateRight").on("click",function(){
            rot += 90;
            rot = rot>360?90:rot;
            CanvasCrop.rotate(rot);
        });
        $("#zoomIn").on("click",function(){
            ratio =ratio*0.9;
            CanvasCrop.scale(ratio);
        });
        $("#zoomOut").on("click",function(){
            ratio =ratio*1.1;
            CanvasCrop.scale(ratio);
        });
        $("#alertInfo").on("click",function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("visbleCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        });
        
        $("#crop").on("click",function(){
            
            var src = CanvasCrop.getDataURL("jpeg");
            //$("body").append("<div style='word-break: break-all;'>"+src+"</div>");  
            $(".container").append("<img class='img1'style='float:right;' name='image' src='"+src+"' />");
   $sr= src;
        });
        
        console.log("ontouchend" in document);
    })
 $().cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('croppedImage', blob);

  $.ajax('index.php', {
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function () {
      console.log('Upload success');
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('Upload error');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    
    .tools{
        margin-top: 20px;
        
    }
    .tools span{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        background-color: #f40;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .clearfix {
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    .clearfix:before{
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after{
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    .cropPoint{
        position: absolute;
        height: 8px;
        width: 8px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .upload-wapper{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        height: 26px;
        line-height: 26px;
        width: 132px;
        background-color: #f40;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #upload-file{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        width: 132px;
        height: 26px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery.CanvasCrop.js DEMO演示</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/canvasCrop.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.canvasCrop.js" ></script>
<div class="container">
   <form action=""role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="imageBox" >
    <!--<div id="img" ></div>-->
    <!--<img class="cropImg" id="img" style="display: none;" src="images/avatar.jpg" />-->
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="thumbBox"></div>
    <div class="spinner" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tools clearfix">
    <span id="rotateLeft" >rotateLeft</span>
    <span id="rotateRight" >rotateRight</span>
    <span id="zoomIn" >zoomIn</span>
    <span id="zoomOut" >zoomOut</span>
    <span id="crop" >Crop</span>
    <span id="alertInfo" >alert</span>
    <div class="upload-wapper">
               Select An Image
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload-file" value="Upload" />
    </div>
 <input type="submit"name="submit"></input>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to crop an image first then upload into database.i am trying to upload cropped image using php .i asked my query here but dont get any response .please share me php code to upload cropped image I want to upload cropped image into database. I am using jquery canvas crop so I can crop the image properly but it is not uploading into database. I tried lots of ways but didn't get success. Please help me out. Give me php code for uploading cropped image. Also i want to resize the image using jquery how can i fullfill this need? please guide me

Comment: guys i posted this issue second time but didn't get proper solution yet.it is really disappointing.is there nobody can help me to out from this situation.i tried lots of but didn't find any solution to  fix it .i really need to be resolve this issue assap so i came here to take help of experienced devlopers.but nobody is helping me to fix this issue.kindly understand my problem and try to resolve it .